# How to use April Tag(Computer vision based localisation) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement April tag in flutter but I don't have any idea how to achieve it, can you help please?

Comment: Can you include more details ?

Comment: I am working on a AR project, to calculate local position I need to implement April tag (Computer vision based localisation) which is very common in python, but my project is on flutter I want to Implement in Flutter

Answer (score 0):

```
*get timeutils package

 static String convertddMMMyy(DateTime date) {
    final DateTime dateTime = date;
    final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MMM-dd');
    final String formattedDate = formatter.format(dateTime);
    return formattedDate;

TimeUtils.convertddMMMyy( 
    DateTime.parse(lowstock.orderedOn!)
        ),
it will give current month tag*
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans, But April tag is different thing, related to computer vision project,